# Averages of the values ​present in multiple files

Tags: python, spyder, mean

I would like to create a vector containing the averages of the values ​​present in multiple files, but comparing the average of the individual files and the vector I don't get the same values ​​and above all I don't get them in the order I want. What could be the problem? How do I ask that the values ​​in the vector be put in the order in which the files are named?
This is the script I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os

#-----------------------input files----------------------------
path = r'C:\Users\suemack528\Desktop\pressure\list_output_pressure' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path + "/*.dat"))
filename = [glob.glob(f'line_output_P{i}') for i in range(55)]

#----------------------join files-----------------------
li = []

for filename in sorted(all_files):
   df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=1, delim_whitespace=True)
   filt_time_value = 15
   df = df[df.time > filt_time_value]
   all_files = df['PRESSURE'].mean()
   li.append(all_files)

P = np.array(li)
```

Comment: I attach the image of the vector I get and the values ​​that I should get from each single file

[what do i get][1]
[what do i get][2]
[what do i get][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0HkO.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybtSK.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqlGn.png

Comment: [what am I supposed to get][4]
[what am I supposed to get][5]
[what am I supposed to get][6]
[what am I supposed to get][7]

  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pd8T.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jgqH.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B05Wj.png
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o6EF.png

Comment: Check if `sorted(all_files)` is actually the order you want?

Comment: *but comparing the average of the individual files* ... where do you do this comparison? Are you running the same `df['time']` filter?

Comment: @mdinaker I tried, but I don't get the order I want

Comment: @Parfait I found what was the problem with the difference in values, thanks

Comment: Please could you provide a list of file names along with the expected output order?

Comment: List of files name: line_output_P1, line_output_P2, ...., line_output_P54 and I'm supposed to obtain the values in this order

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the order, you have to pay attention to how Python sorts strings.
For example:

```
sorted(['1', '2', '10'])
>> ['01', '10', '02']
```

vs:

```
sorted(['01', '02', '10'])
>> ['01', '02', '10']
```

Since it looks like you want the second one, you might want to rename your files to have the same number of digits in the numeric part. For example, line_output_P01, line_output_P02 and so on.

Comment: Easier than expected! Thanks, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a pandas Series that can index file name with mean value (also interchangeable to numpy array with `to_numpy`). Also, save the filename with each data frame in list and then sort. In fact, all can be handled via a list comprehension and `pandas.concat`.

```py
agg_list = [(pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=1, delim_whitespace=True)
               .assign(filename = filename)
               .query("time > 15")
               .groupby(["filename"])["PRESSURE"].mean()
            ) for filename in sorted(all_files)]

pressure_mean_df = pd.concat(agg_list).sort_index()

pressure_mean_arry = pressure_mean_df.to_numpy()
```